# Execute Array stored in a variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, eval, telegram-bot

I stored an array in the variable **$stringPedidos**. I'm trying to use this variable as an array in **$resp** but it's not working.

I'm trying to display a keyboard that contains the product names depending on a user order ID extracted from the db. The $stringPedidos variable contains the array needed for displaying the keyboard at a Telegram Bot using PHP. I want to use $stringPedidos as an array, the problem is that $stringPedidos is executed as a string.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE usuario_id='".$id."'");

      if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

        $stringPedidos= "array(";

        $query = "SELECT producto_id FROM pedidos WHERE usuario_id='".$id."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
            $producto_id = $row['producto_id'];

                 $queryProductos = "SELECT name FROM productos WHERE id='".$producto_id."'";
                    $resultProductos = mysqli_query($conn, $queryProductos) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                    while ($rowProductos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultProductos, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                        $productoName = $rowProductos["name"];
                          $stringPedidos .= 'array("'.$productoName.'"),';


                                      }

        }

        $stringPedidos .= 'array("Return↩️")';
        $stringPedidos .= ")";


    $resp = array("keyboard" => eval($stringPedidos),"resize_keyboard" => true,"one_time_keyboard" => true,"remove_keyboard" => true);
```

}

Output: array(array("testProduct"),array("testProduct2"),array("Return↩️"))

The output is right, but it's not executed as an array, because it isn't working.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. If you go back one step. What exactly do you want to achieve with your code?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` < add that at the top of your php file(s) and tell us what you get back.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld thank you for your comment. I'm trying to display a keyboard that contains the product names depending on a user order ID extracted from the db. The $stringPedidos variable contains the array needed for displaying the keyboard at a Telegram Bot using PHP. I want to use $stringPedidos as an array, the problem is that $stringPedidos is executed as a string.

Comment: Why are you using `eval()`?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it's a Telegram Bot, I think that I cannot display that errors.

Comment: @AlonEitan it was a mistake, thank you. Unfortunately that wasn't the problem.

Comment: I want to help but I don't understand the problem, is it with creating the data structure? Can you please include an example of the expected output and the actual one?

Comment: @AlonEitan the two while() instructions adds to the $stringPedidos variable the data from the db, and it also insert the structure needed for making it as an array. So after executing all the code, the $stringPedidos output is: array(array("testProduct"),array("testProduct2"),array("Return↩️")).

If I put that output manually instead of $stringPedidos, all work fine. But I want to use the variable $stringPedidos.

Comment: Please put your code and expected result in your actual question. It's a lot easier to understand then.

Comment: @dmquilez I see. Let me check

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I've just edited the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You cannot not include an array in a string. You're basically just storing the textvalue array now. Therefore the textvalue array is in the result output.

Comment: @dmquilez Try [this code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aca7aa351e828cb7c432c7eed11b2d17766a142c) - I didn't test it for bugs, but let me know if it helps

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you so much! That array solution is way better than using eval(), I'm going to implement that to my project. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @dmquilez Glad to help :) Please read the notification about using [evel()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is to add `eval("\$newStringPedidos = $stringPedidos;");` before the last line. This will store your array in a new variable `$newStringPedidos`. Now the variable `$newStringPedidos` is really an array and not a string, so you can use it in the last line and it shall work.

```
eval("\$newStringPedidos = $stringPedidos;");
$resp = array("keyboard" => $newStringPedidos,"resize_keyboard" => true,"one_time_keyboard" => true,"remove_keyboard" => true);
```

The problem is that you are using the eval() function incorrectly. Visit https://www.w3schools.com/pHP/func_misc_eval.asp

Furthermore, it is usually much better to avoid eval() function, since it is quite confusing and in your case I think you really do not need it.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works! How do you think I can implement that in a better way? 

Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome. To evoid eval(), use an array from the begining. set `$stringPedidos = array();` and whenever you add something add it to the array instead of adding it as a string. More precisely, in your code instead of `$stringPedidos .= 'array("'.$productoName.'"),';` use `$stringPedidos[] = $productoName`. This is just to give you some ideas, I am not familiar with your database.